# LTC2498: different voltage on input and muxout

Tags: adc, schematics, rtd

I am measuring RTD (4-wire connection) with an AD [LTC2498](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2498fg.pdf) ADC. The ADC responds to commands via SPI, so does return data. The problem is that the voltage at Vn/Vp does not match the one at muxoutpn/muxoutnn (2.67/2.62 vs 2.64/2.64). Why can that happen?

[Falstad sim](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0mRMDMAmMZkHZIFYAsixtFsA2QkXCbCxEbAUwFo0AoAJxEYE4TwNfuvZLkhRwYSCwDuIRAA5cddDWRLVkgMYq127PzFgmcqNDAlsFuVyy5sqZJGMw4YabuV7e2ZYnYhMqt6qiIheyqIScH4BFGayobG8EXCSHDG4uMbpPGLYLm4hYcEKOpIyhYmyJZRJbjFB-hiquDmSAOYUcqKend1c6lAsWhnGNRSZFCSKEUay0MgokBhc8A62cshJsPAsHZmiuFO9x6JlVYpjI5VnV2M9Y75pTXQZjYH6opjtb3T69f1iM7pOIxUJOPxxNCqSEfcApFIQ3hgfQg0gGeFRDiopG8RbojGI-xonLINHJTHgJH6HLIpJwqJaGmvGmwwyMYyMRDzLg8%20TEMAKawkBYmfKMoTE3GQabgWZchaoETwULWORq0U7Do5PHahKnNwktG0om1GQsqkWwYyY3G4QRP5uW1ou0m-xuTnQlGWs7YzgofwiK1%201Quj0-b5xPGRvVBsN4uMkcEyBNZZ5gwYAJUp4mhyihgIooi5tFOJmwfjDMTjDnx8LqzyuwNNPzwinq4T88gukeqE1OsFcHC7OmHLTpzlcWlH2t7Tg1Lj9sBI5gc0sIXEQWGozh2HCZijMEVe-c1lKPB4BYGPgz3UsU2prJ8Hun0%201%2044HfluRzfhxlE4hP4jT%20QMn0Ay0bQBMCtFtQNIIGNkOWcEgMGWOQQjkQgBQwfANVcZNzU4GkfHdElA0EWRE1kR0kWUMN8xuCZ0x6dNfAAD04MAN3EWhmEgWg0F4NtFAANQASwAOwAfQABwAeykFgOOYbiBWoZhiHAdVhJAESZKkySlM4lYA0UDSQ1wDAKADXTpMM5S1MorhOK42QGxskSACMAEMAGd6CMkh4FkK8QHMRQCCsnSAGEAHkAFlApwWIrOXZoax0kS2HoAAzAAdGSkrCURzDCWhMuynLGCMxhkDqyYBEOSZnJ0wAkEEAXhBAGEQQAhEEAARBAA4QPLfMAFhBAAYQbrAHEQfrAC4QUajM2ahkRDVSMGoTLCo4haiSs5BuM2A4PIkitiNUejwhMZ8KNDf0XX7S7tSolNAVMY7LXo2EYFcTzOFJXguk4MgKE2IM6oimtQfGJN-GESHocUBogRhhp23UOoYbxFjHxYIA) (matches measurements)

ADC connection. At the top is a multiplexer that activates subschemas to the left to ADC (one per channel). High-res (clickable):

[image: adc connection. To the top is multiplexer that activates subschemas to the left to adc (one per channel)]

Subschema to left to the ADC in detail, simulated in Falstad (see above):

[image: subschema to left to the adc detailed]

EDIT
I noticed that it takes approximately 600 milliseconds for muxout to match Vin. If to read out data and start new conversion just after end-of-conversion signal (approximately 7.5 samples per second), muxoutp=muxoutn= (Vn+Vp)/2. If sampling period grows over 200ms, muxouts become different and approach corresponding Vin. If the period is >600ms, muxoutn=Vn, muxoutp=Vp. I have two options: there are problems with adc or opamp, or I really failed with schematics.

Comment: The schematic is fuzzy and it hard to determine what you’re asking. How are you determining the voltages? Direct measurement with a multimeter and/or from the adc readings?

Comment: Direct measurements with multimeter. I measure Vn/Vp at c41/42 and muxout directly from opamp

Comment: Updated top picture with more high-res version. Is it ok now?

Comment: Is it possible that Ri of the multimeter affects the reading at C41 and C42?

Comment: It is possible, but please see the recent edit